# Jquery: How to highlight some numbers in bold within a numeric sequence from 0 to 99 after a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a numeric sequence from 0 to 99:

0 1 2 3 4 5 . . . 99

In this case, i'm trying to put some numbers in bold after clicking a button. For example, within a first input there is the number 2 and within a second input there is the number 99, and after clicking on a button, the number 2 and 99 are in bold as below:

0 1 **2** 3 4 5 . . . **99**

I tried to find some similar questions, but unfortunatly i didn't find some solution to improve my script yet:

1. [Jquery how to check if a input has a number higher then 99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704957/jquery-how-to-check-if-a-input-has-a-number-higher-then-99)
2. [I Want To Print 1 to 100 Numbers Using Arrays In Javascript Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544993/i-want-to-print-1-to-100-numbers-using-arrays-in-javascript-only)
3. [How to format numbers by prepending 0 to single-digit numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043026/how-to-format-numbers-by-prepending-0-to-single-digit-numbers)

At first i'm trying with the following HTML code and a jquery script to apply this solution, but i'm not able to improve it to get the final result:

**HTML code:**

```html
<input type="number" id="field1" value="2"/>
<br>
<input type="number" id="field2" value="99"/>
<br>
<button type="button" id="getBtn">show me the highlighted numbers</button>
<br>

<div id="sequence"></div>
```

**Jquery script to call click event:**

```
$('#getBtn').on( "click", function() {

  var field1 = $('#field1').val();
  var field2 = $('#field2').val();

// From this point, i don't know how to improve the script to display a sequence number with the highlighted numbers.

for(let i = 0;i <= 100;i++){

    console.log(i);

}

$("#sequence").html();


});
```

How can i improve my script to find a viable solution?

Comment: Why do you use a console.log? You should append the number into a div tag's innerText wrapping up your number inside the bold tag. E.g: "<b>" + i +"</b>"

Comment: Actually, I just left it as a way to consult the result through the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of strings (wrapping the number in a `<strong>` element when it's one of the inputs) and then join on space at the end to create the HTML.

```js
$('#getBtn').click(function(e) {
  const vals = $('input[type=number][id^=field]').map((i, el) => el.valueAsNumber).get();
  const seq = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    seq.push(vals.includes(i) ? `<strong>${i}</strong>` : i);
  $("#sequence").html(seq.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="field1" value="2" />
<br>
<input type="number" id="field2" value="99" />
<br>
<button type="button" id="getBtn">show me the highlighted numbers</button>
<br>
<div id="sequence"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will improve the script with this solution.